# how to detect click events on three.js sprite

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to detect a click event on a three.js sprite here's the code:

```
function bindEvents(state) {
  let intersected;
  function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const mouseX = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
    const mouseY = - (event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

    const camera = state.threeD.elements.camera;
    const raycaster = state.threeD.raycaster;

    raycaster.setFromCamera(new THREE.Vector2(mouseX, mouseY), camera);

    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(state.clickables?state.clickables:[]);
    if (intersects.length > 0) {
      if (intersected) intersected.material.map = intersected.currentMap;
      intersected = intersects[0].object;
      intersected.currentMap = intersected.material.map;
      intersected.material.map = selectCityTexture(128, '#cccccc', 'cccccc');
    }

  }

  document.addEventListener('mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false);
  document.addEventListener('touchstart', onDocumentMouseDown, false);
}
```

This almost works, the mouse position is offset by some amount. Probably some calculation error, I have no idea how the above code works please help.

Comment: Try it with the code from this official example: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_raycast_sprite

Answer (score 0):

```
const mouseX = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
const mouseY = - (event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
```

these are changed with

```
const mouseX = (event.clientX / canvas.width) * 2 - 1;
const mouseY = - (event.clientY / canvas.height) * 2 + 1;
```